# Cypress.io with Testcafe

Tags: testing, automated-tests, cypress, e2e-testing, testcafe

Are there any added advantages to using Cypress instead of TestCafe? while comparing usages with developer friendliness, are there any added advantages using Cypress.io

Answer (score 3):

This is difficult to answer, especially when you don't provide us with any insight into your context. These are not identical products, they might be suitable for slightly different use cases.

I can tell you my personal opinion of the two, but that might not apply to your situatio(s), so I just recommend reading documentation:

- https://docs.cypress.io/guides/overview/why-cypress.html
- https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/

and trying the products on some real projects.

Some areas to consider:

- what you want to automate
- who needs to maintain the tests - how well people know JavaScript, Cypress, in my opinion, requires more knowledge in this area which seems to bring a lot of trouble to many people
- reading carefully [trade-offs](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Permanent-trade-offs-1) and [best practices](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/best-practices.html) in Cypress - if you don't already follow many of these practices, you might find it really hard to completely switch to Cypress
- documentation support - this is exceptional in Cypress, really good docs online, with tons of examples, you rarely see this with other technologies
- both products have some additional paid features, have a look on what you need to use
- integrations with other services - CI, browserstack and the like
- etc.